# Continue uploading NSData even connection lost/user clicked on home NSUrlConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, uiimage, nsurlconnection

I need to upload via HTTP Post `NSData` which is `UIImage` or `NSUrl` of a video file via the iPhone app which I develop for ios6

I need to support the following cases:

1. The user clicked on home - to continue uploading in background
2. The connection is lost - to continue uploading when there is a new internet connection even if the user left the app by clicking on the home button)
3. The user quit the app (clicked on x) and it was in the middle of uploading, next time that he would open the app, it will continue

In case 2 and 3:

1. It will continue from the same location that it was in the NSData (not start from the beginning of the file)
2. It will send in the new call a variable index={index} (where index is the amount of times that it continues starting from 0

I know how to use `NSURLConnection` as an async connection. But how to support the above 3 cases?

Comment: Check out `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, those delegate methods are pretty verbose.

Comment: I know them - but can't understand who didFail helps to continue from the same location

Comment: Oh then you should see `NSURLSession` - that has many more tools for continuing failed/paused transmissions. You can use that instead of `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: im developing for ios6. is is good also for it?

Comment: No, sorry but `NSURLSession` is iOS 7 and OS X 10.9 up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work you need 2 things:

1. A record, stored persistently, of how much data has been uploaded to the server.
2. A server which accepts the `Content-Range` header and can handle storing partial uploads and completing them later. (or a server with an API to handle the same function).

If you have both of these things then you can perform the task using `NSURLConnection` and its delegate methods, `NSUserDefaults` (or similar) to store the progress information and `subdataWithRange:` (or perhaps `NSFileHandle`) to get only the data which needs to be uploaded.

---

Look at using `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` to get updates of what data has been sent. Store that number (if not all of the data has been sent) into user defaults. Once all the data has been sent, remove the number from user defaults.

Use `subdataWithRange:` by creating a range from the stored number to the `(total length of data - the number`).

Comment: I have #2, can u give an example of subdatawithrange for an image file? as well, which method shall I use to save how much data I have sent?